# Update subdoc without delete other fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, rethinkdb

I want to update subdoc using object but not delete other fields ( like [rethinkdb-update](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/) ), cause I'm converting a system from rethinkdb to mongodb.

```
User : {
  _id: "",
  profile: { name: "Joe", age: 20, gender: "male" },
}

const params = { profile : { age: 30 } }

UserModel.update({ _id: "id" }, params, null, () => {});

// expected result
{ 
  _id: "", 
  profile: { name: "Joe", age: 30, gender: "male" } 
}
```

Is it possible to do this in mongo (mongoose) ?

Answer (score 0):

As Felix already said, you can't do it on another way if u go natively.

U can use Mongoose like this:

```
UserModel.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);
```